# How to fix scrollview size in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Why change scrollview size, when I change view as

When I click view as : iPhone X in storyboard, below this image

[image]

But when I click other device such as iPad, iPhone SE, my scroll view image like this:

[image]

I used autolayout so other image and scrollview same size. 
Only this scrollview changing size

```
func DetailImageView() {
    DetailScrollArray = [DetailScroll1,DetailScroll2,DetailScroll3]
    DetailScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    DetailScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width * CGFloat(DetailScrollArray.count), height : self.view.bounds.height)
    DetailScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    DetailScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    //DetailScrollView.clipsToBounds = true

    DetailScrollView.delegate = self

    for (index,Scroll) in DetailScrollArray.enumerated() {
        if let scrollView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SV", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ScrollViewCell {
            scrollView.ScrollImage.image = UIImage(named: Scroll["image"]!)

            scrollView.ScrollImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill  // Aspect Fill 
            scrollView.ScrollImage.clipsToBounds = true
            DetailScrollView.addSubview(scrollView)
            scrollView.ScrollImage.frame.size.width = self.DetailScrollView.bounds.size.width
            scrollView.frame.size.width = self.DetailScrollView.bounds.size.width
            scrollView.ScrollImage.frame.size.height = self.DetailScrollView.bounds.size.height
            //scrollView.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            scrollView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * self.view.bounds.size.width

            //scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        }
    }
}
```

I used same code other view controller.
I can see same size on other view controller.

Comment: Seems you want to create a Pagination type effect using ScrollView that allows to scroll through multiple images example in Gallery, Also set ScrollView height and width as **Main Screen bounds** and change its **ContentSize**

Comment: create an uiimageview and then add to scroll view

Comment: what's effect when setting scrollView.ScrollImage.contentMode to aspect fill? or aspect fit?